# Create node via REST from Android app

Tags: 8

I use restful between Drupal 7 and Android app.
I logged in  successful and got 3 variable session_id, session_name and token
When I use POST method to create node. I getting error : "node type is required"
This is my code :

```
private class addArticleTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Integer> {

    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://mysite/endpoint/node");

        try {

            //get title and body UI elements
            TextView txtTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTitle);
            TextView txtBody = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editBody);

            //extract text from UI elements and remove extra spaces
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            String title=txtTitle.getText().toString().trim();
            String body=txtBody.getText().toString().trim();


            //add raw json to be sent along with the HTTP POST request
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity("{ \"title\" : \"Sample post\" , \"type\" : \"article\" , \"body\" : { \"und\" :[{ \"value\" : \"comments about something\" }]} }");
            se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
            se.setContentType(new BasicHeader("Cookie",session_name+"="+session_id));
            se.setContentType(new BasicHeader("X-CSRF-Token",token));
            httppost.setEntity(se);


            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            Log.v("Return add article", EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));


            return 0;

        }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("Error adding article",e.getMessage());
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

In Logcat : Return add article : ["node type is required"]
any one help me.

Comment: I think your post URL should be `http://mysite/endpoint/node.json`

Comment: @tyler.frankenstein I edit URL and I still have this issue

Comment: hi. did you solved that error?

Answer (score 1):

You must mention the node type while doing the POST.

**node_type will the machine name of your content type**

for example try creating page with this,

```
StringEntity se = new StringEntity("{ \"title\" : \"Sample post\" , \"page\" :
```

Comment: Yes, I have mention the node type in command : `StringEntity se = new StringEntity("{ \"title\" : \"Sample post\" , \"type\" : \"article\" , \"body\" : { \"und\" :[{ \"value\" : \"comments about something\" }]} }");`

Comment: I test with Postman by command : `{"type":"article","title":"test title"}` and succesfull